# Pypi upload without a .pypirc?

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

This thing drives me nuts. Isn't it possible to simply do something like below?

```
python setup.py sdist upload --username me --password 1234
```

Or be promped to enter a password with:

```
python setup.py sdist upload --username me
```

Being forced to use my password in clear text in a configuration file goes against everything I ever learned about security. Also not being able to manually enter a username and a password is user unfriendly.

Are Python folks from an other universe? Is there a reason they try to make our lives hard?

Comment: Giving a password in clear text on the command line is really bad, too. As far as I know, if you're using passwords, the only particularly secure way of requesting it is through `getpass()` (or a similar mechanism in other languages.) Possibly a tkinter text box which doesn't reveal characters entered would well, too.

Comment: If you give a password in clear text on the command line, it's trivial for someone to find it by running a command line `top` which shows all running processes and the arguments passed to them.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you are right, however I am mostly bothered with this from the usage perspective than security.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Don't forget `.bash_history` and friends!

Comment: @Kevin: I never realized `.bash_history` was a thing before now. That's another vulnerability - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Kevin: Would something like `os.system("blah --password 1234")` show up in `.bash_history` (I'm on Windows right now so can't check for myself.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I doubt it.  History is [a convenience for the user](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=241694).  It wouldn't make sense for it to store anything that wasn't entered interactively.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) instead of `setup.py` for uploading.  This has a number of other advantages.  In particular, you can test the files before you upload them.  It is invoked like this:

```
twine upload --username me --password hunter2 dist/whatever.whl
```

Please note that putting a password on the command line is dangerous.  It will likely be recorded in `~/.bash_history`, or your shell's equivalent.